# Kartik GridView Yii2 : Toggle data not working in toolbar

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I am using Yii2 kartik gridview. Below are the 2 images before and after toggleData button is clicked. I am unable to see Full data in gridview.

**BEFORE**

[image]

**AFTER**

[image]

Only the pagination goes away but gridview does not display all records. I have 10 records for now, I have set pagination to 5 records. So If I click on "All", I must get all 10 records, but as you see I only get 5 records.

Below is code for ActiveDataProvider before rendering page.

**CODE INSIDE CONTROLLER ACTION**

```
 $searchModel = new StudentsAdminSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(\Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        return \Yii::$app->controller->render('student/student_list', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
```

**CODE INSIDE StudentAdminSearch**

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => Constants::$PAGE_SIZE, // $PAGE_SIZE=5
            ],
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something else, much easy and reliable than session variable.

If you see, when i first land on list page I get a **link** in address bar like,

```
http://localhost/nse/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fstudent-list
```

When I click '**ALL**' button as toggleButton inside Kartik GridView, I get a **link** in address bar like,

```
http://localhost/nse/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fstudent-list&_tog1149016d=all
```

If you see carefully I get extra parameter added as **_tog1149016d** with value "**all**". With different installations ans servers the number with '_tog' changes. So, Inside Search Model's search Method I did Something like this,

```
$pagination = Utility::getPagination($params);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'pagination' => $pagination,
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

I wrote a small utility function to check request param whether it contains "all" or "page" or nothing.

```
public static function getPagination($request_params){
    $param_val = 'page';
    foreach($request_params as $key => $value){
        if (strpos($key, '_tog') !== false) {
            $param_val = $value;
        }
    }
    $pagination = array();
    if($param_val == 'all'){ //returns empty array, which will show all data.
        return $pagination;
    }else if($param_val == 'page'){ //return pageSize as 5
        $pagination = ['pageSize' => 5];
        return $pagination;
    }
    return $pagination;  // returns empty array again.
}
```

Above code Works like charm. I am attaching proof of implementation and running scenarios below,

**ON CLICKING "Page"** (It enables pagination, my case, it is 5)

[image]

**ON CLICKING "All"** (It populates all data)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As your Active data provider is having the limit to show only 5 limit which is constant every time you get the data you will get 5 records only so you can use the yii2 session to set the data on click of toggle some thing like this

```
    $size=\Yii::$app->session->get('user.size');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => isset($size) ? $size : 5,
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'defaultOrder' => [
                'id' => SORT_DESC,
            ]
        ],
    ]);
```

where user.size is the session value want or u can also remove the pagination size to get all data if size is not there

```
$notshowsize=\Yii::$app->session->get('user.size');
  $pagination = array();
if($notshowsize){
 $pagination = array();
 }else{
   $pagination = ['pageSize' => isset($size) ? $size : 5]
 }
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
    'pagination' => $pagination,
    'sort' => [
        'defaultOrder' => [
            'id' => SORT_DESC,
        ]
    ],
]);
```

where variable $notshowsize is boolean set to show data in pagination or not

Comment: how to write code in toggle button?? I mean 'toolbar' =>  [
            '{toggleData}',
            '{export}'
        ]      So where do I need to write the above code only for toggledata?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem, added a static function as following like improved version of above.

```
public static function getPagination($request_params){
    $param_val = 'page';
    foreach($request_params as $key => $value){
        if (strpos($key, '_tog') !== false) {
            $param_val = $value;
        }
    }
    $pagination = array();
    if($param_val == 'all'){ //returns empty array, which will show all data.
        $pagination = ['pageSize' => false];

    }else if($param_val == 'page'){ //return pageSize as 5
        $pagination = ['pageSize' => 20];

    }else{
        $pagination = ['pageSize' => false];

    }
    return $pagination;  // returns empty array again.
}
```